# How to make 2 objects of one?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I want to slice an object in Blender into two pieces, but I can not get it done. If I use the Mesh tool Bisect it doesn't slice it rightly where I want it slices how i don't want it. I want to slice all the object to get two pieces. Please give me some information how I can do it rightly or how I can use knife tool to slice it. I don't know how I can merge all the object to one object and then slice it.

Here is what I have now
[image]

and I what to slice it to get two objects something like this

[image]

So I can move half of the dog up and half of the dog down.

When I use Bisect it doesn't slice it correctly how I want.

Comment: Hi. Can you post a screenshot of the object that you are trying to split?

Comment: @satishgoda , I made edit with screenshoot of object ... Idk how to slice it correctly.

Comment: If you want to join all the objects into one, just select them and press Ctrl+J. Note that since your objects were created as curves and then converted to meshes you might end up with very messy topology. To cut, you might want to create a cube as a separate object, place the cube where you want the cut and then use a boolean modifier.

Comment: @cegaton . 

If i am right if i place cube that will cut only cube not my dog object.. I need to cut my dog object not the new object of cube.. please help me , thank you :))

Comment: Use the boolean on the dog, to use the cube as the cutting object.

Comment: I still didnt got the right answer how i can do it to get to objects from one. I dont know how to use boolean..

Answer (score 2):

You can slice the object in two by using the Boolean modifier.

Here's how to use it do to this: 
Step 1-Add a cube and scale it down on the Y axis until it bisects your object in the middle where you want two objects.

Step 2-Add a *Boolean* modifier to the object you are splitting, and make sure that the operation is set to difference.

Step 3-Make the object that modifier affects to your cube. Now you should notice in wireframe view that the object looks like it has a small breakage on both sides of the cube.

Step 4-apply the boolean modifier and delete the cube. 
There should be a break in the object that separates it into two parts.

Now, select the object and go into edit mode. 
Press 'P' on your computer keyboard, and select the option "separate by loose parts".

Blender has now separated the object into two individual meshes, and that should solve your problem.

Comment: You can also just select the things that you want to be divided into 1 part and just separate them by parts/ by selected parts. Boolean can also be used, since it allows you to have a reference of what faces would be in either parts.

Comment: That's why I use boolean.

Comment: Yup. Does the work anyways.